# Dynamically change app icon getting app close automatically in Android Module React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

In my scenario, I am updating the app icon dynamically by using below code but whenever I am updating the icon, at the time I am getting application closing but icon is update. How to prevent the app closing.

**My Code**

```
@ReactMethod
public void changeIcon(String enableIcon) {
    final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
    PackageManager pm = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    System.out.println(activity.getComponentName());
    //Remove old icons
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(activity.getComponentName(),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    //Display new icons
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(activity.getBaseContext(),enableIcon),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean application crash on running this code, but icon update successfully?

Comment: @gpl Icon is updated successfully but application is closed without error.

Comment: are you restarting the same activity?

Comment: @gpl I am not restarting. But the same activity I need to stay.

Answer (score 0):

Don't enable/disable activity. Make activity aliases. You can give different labels (which display as app name) and icon to each alias. You must give different name (used for reference) to each alias.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
     <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter
</activity>

<activity-alias
        android:label="Red app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_red"
        android:name=".RED"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
        android:label="Blue app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_blue"
        android:name=".BLUE"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
        android:label="Green app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_green"
        android:name=".GREEN"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

Switch icon by enabling-disabling these aliases. It would be better if you make enum, which would make things clear. Use this code to switch between different activity aliases:

KOTLIN

```
enum class ICON_COLOUR { RED, BLUE, GREEN }

private fun setIcon(targetColour: ICON_COLOUR) {
    for (value in ICON_COLOUR.values()) {
        val action = if (value == targetColour) {
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
        } else {
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED
        }
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.${value.name}"),
            action, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }
}
```

JAVA (enum version)

```
private enum ICON_COLOUR {
    RED("RED"), 
    GREEN("GREEN"), 
    BLUE("BLUE"), 
 
    private String color;
 
    Environment(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
 
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}

private void setIcon(ICON_COLOUR targetColour) {
    int action;
    for (ICON_COLOUR value : ICON_COLOUR.values()) {
        if (value == targetColour)
            action = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
        else
            action = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
            
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, value.getColor()),
            action, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

JAVA (String-array version)

```
private String []iconColour = {"RED", "GREEN",  "BLUE"};

private void setIcon(String targetColour) {
    int action;
    for (String value : iconColour) {
        if (value.equals(targetColour))
            action = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
        else
            action = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
            
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, value),
            action, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am checking it.

Comment: Could you please update my code, because I am getting errors in fun setIcon many places. Looks like you given example for Kotlin but I need Java code

Comment: please check it.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol error facing here enum static class ICON_COLOUR { RED, GREEN, BLUE };

Comment: I am getting error at pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    new ComponentName(package, value.getColor(),action), PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP); `package` unexpected token error and `action),` getting expected ; error and also last point DONT_KILL_APP)`;` expected token error.

Comment: also I am calling this method from ReactNative. So can I call it like `setIcon(ICON_COLOUR,"GREEN");`. Is there anything possible to change `setIcon(String ICON_COLOUR);`?

Comment: Check it now. Some semi-colon(;) are missing and BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID is used to get package name. Sorry, I have no experience of ReactNative.

Comment: is it possible to change `ICON_COLOUR targetColour` to `String targetColour` because I can pass string from react native while calling this method.

Comment: Actually we are using enum with String values. We used enum for just to make our code more user friendly. If you prefer String array I can do that.

Comment: I am calling from React native `ToastExample.setIcon("GREEN")` like that. It will call the setIcon native method along with parameters. Icon is changing fine but I dont know why app is closing while every time changing icon.

Comment: Yes you said that and I said that sorry I don't know  React Native. I could replace enum with String array if you prefer that

Comment: Yes Please change it, I will try if it works fine then will close it soon. Thank you so much

Comment: I am checking now. I will update it here quickly. Thank you so much for your kind help

Comment: if I call `ToastExample.setIcon("RED");` like this I am getting error like Compoenent  class RED does not exist error.

Comment: still app is getting closing.

Comment: yes app  closing when i change app icon from old new or new to old can we prevent this when change app icon in background it should update don't want restart app